# How can I stop google maps navigation from my app?

Tags: android, google-maps

I've seen the Ola driver app do this. They have a floating icon on google maps when they start navigation and when clicks, it stops google maps navigation and returns to their app. I want to do something similar from my app.

Comment: You can't. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents) are the actions exposed by Google Maps Intents

Comment: You need to create a Floating button which take back you to your application. For this you can create a service which run in background and show your float button on all screen.

Comment: I got the floating action button part. I did not get the part on how to close the google maps activity that I had started.